# Product Name, ID, Code are not appearing under custom report

Tags: reporting, opportunity, product

I have a custom report type called Opportunities with Transactions. Opportunities has a custom field called ProductIndex which is a lookup field to Product. For some reason on this report, Product Name, Code, and ID are all appearing to be null. I've checked ProductIndex's, Name's, and Code's field level security and they are visible to everyone. Any help will be much appreciated.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: so an Opportunity can have only a single Product?

Comment: It's weird because there's that field as well as the Product related list which has multiple products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The ProductIndex field was not set on all the Opportunities so there was no Product Name, Code, ID to pull and appear. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: But if questions are resolved, and the answer is simple, we want to see it here, and accepted right ?  Updates that resolve the question to the question itself leave the question unanswered and may be unhelpful to others who face the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

3 other places to check:

1. Profile Security
2. Org defaults
3. Make sure the data is really there (probably by using the developer console)